# Overwrite the url in .htaccess file for django

Tags: django, .htaccess, django-urls

I want to change the structure of the displayed client-side URL. I'm not too skilled using regex and coding for the .htaccess file. Basically, I have a structure that looks something like:

```
www.abc.com/login/?lang=es
```

I would like this to be displayed in the address bar as:

`www.abc.com/login/es`

So please tell me how i can overwrite the existing url in my .htaccess file.

Thanks

**EDIT**

My directory listing

`

> myproject

------------- >my application

------------- >settings/url directory

> media
>   templates`

Comment: I don't understand why you would create your URLs in that format in the first place. Django understands the second format natively: the usual reason for the first one is to use with PHP CMSs that only accept query parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is go through all of your code and change your login links to look like:

```
www.abc.com/login/es
```

It'll save you an extra connection and redirect.

Then you need rules in your htaccess file in the **www.abc.com** document root to redirect the client when the request is made for `/login/?lang=something` to the nicer looking URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST|HEAD)\ /login/?\?lang=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /login/%2? [L,R=301]
```

Then you need rules to *internally rewrite* the nicer looking URL *back* to the one that has the query string:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?login/(.*)$ /login/?lang=$1 [L]
```

If the base URI has changed (from say, `/login` to `/login/es`), you may need to include a base URI in your login page so that relative links will still resolve correctly. You can do this by adding this tag in your page's header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.......right now i am working on live server so can you tell me where i have to place this .htaccess file

I have edit my question which shows the directoey listing of my project